# Indian English usage of "na"

Tags: subcontinental-english

I have heard a lot of conversations end up in the word "na" mainly among in youth of India.
For example:

> You know naa.
>
> You have phone naa.

Does this make any sense? Is it a development in Indian English?

Comment: I thought it was Hindi for "yes, OK, uhuh"; it's just a filler. Unfortunately our Gujarati/Hindi-speaker isn't in today to ask.

Comment: Note that “Is its too a development in the Indian English?” fails to qualify as Standard English in at least three different ways.

Comment: Is it naa or na? I haven't heard it (on the other hand, I've only heard Indian English spoken in SE Asia and the USA), but if it does mean some kind of 'yes', then it's be appropriate for a verification tag, like English _yes?, OK?, eh?_. Malay has a bunch of focus particles (_lah, pun_) that can be scattered through a sentence to mark the important words, but they have no other functions or meanings.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sounds a lot like a “, no?” tag-question to me, *¿verdad?*

Comment: "Na" in Hindi is used a lot by people in India while speaking in English as if to reinforce to themselves that whatever they are talking about is correct. And hence, *You know, na?* which could almost mean *You know, isn't?* and that "isn't" is usually added as an unconscious self-confidence booster in the end.

Comment: In fact I have only seen "na" used by people who are not too proficient in English and hence not that confident while speaking. This "na" goes to give them some sort of self-assurance that whatever they are speaking is making sense to the listener.

Answer (score 4):

It think such words are the easy short-cut way to turn a sentence into a question without much words and puts the other person under the obligation of responding to it, with 'yeah' or something like it. 
Sri Lankans, on the other hand, attach the word 'no' to the end of their sentences. Depending on the tone in which it is said, it can mean the English equivalent of 'isn't it?' again eliciting a 'yes' from the one to whom it is said like in the sentence, 'This movie is boring no?' or it can mean 'will you' in the sentence 'Tell your brother to come no!".